# Select innerHTML from First <td> of Last <tr> -- jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some rows in a table like this: `<tr class="problem_display_work>` which have two `<td>`s each.

I'm trying to select/alert the innerHTML like this: `alert($('tr.problem_display_work td:first-child').innerHTML);` but it's not working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `alert($('tr.problem_display_work:last-child > td:first-child').html());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
alert($('tr.problem_display_work td:first').html());
```

edit for last tr

```
alert($('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').html());
```

Comment: Ya but OP wants last TR, here it will return first TD html of **first** TR

Comment: then just do alert($('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').html());

Comment: Ya exactly even if `:last` and `:first` aren't CSS selector but jQuery pseudo ones. If possible, better is to use plain CSS one, `:last-child` and `:first-child`, using querySelectorAll() DOM method

Comment: Why would querySelectorAll be better when you already have jQuery loaded?

Comment: @mplungjan I meant jQuery would use internally `querySelectorAll()` unlike if using jq pseudo selectors. BUT it doesn't really matter in most cases for sure

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote could work, but you would need extract javascript object from youre jquery object.  This is done simply by adding `[0]` to your jquery selector. So

```
alert($('tr.problem_display_work td:first-child').innerHTML)
```

would work if you did

```
alert($('tr.problem_display_work td:first-child')[0].innerHTML)
```

Comment: figured i could help him learn something new thats beneficial in the long run.

Comment: But .html() is the method to use when not mixing DOM and jQuery so it is worth pointing that out too?

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("tr.problem_display_work :first-child").text());
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You should try both:

```
alert($('tr.problem_display_work td:first').html());
alert($('tr.problem_display_work td').first().html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this, as it does not depend on css classes.

```
alert($('tr:last-child td:first-child').html());
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
alert($('.problem_display_work td:first-child').innerHTML);
```

Comment: There is no innerHTML defined for a jQuery object. .get(0).innerHTML or just .html()